# Disable v-dialog persistent animation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-model

I am using the [v-dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/) component from vuetify with the persistent tag currently in my project.

```
<v-dialog hide-overlay persistent>
    <v-card></v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Now, persistent prevents the user from closing the dialog by clicking outside. However, there is an bounce off effect when the user clicks outside. I would like to disable this bounce off effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`no-click-animation`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/#no-click-animation) prop :

```
 <v-dialog
        v-model="dialog"
        persistent
        max-width="290"
        no-click-animation
    >
   ...
```